# Finding duplicates in PIg

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

If I have a table with **duplicate rows for an id**,

I can find it using Hive with the follwoing query

```
create table dupe as select * from table1 group by id having count(*) > 1;
```

Can we perform the same function using Pig?

If yes, can someone please help me with that?

Answer (score 5):

The following codes may help you:

```
r1 = load ...;
r2 = group r1 by id;
r3 = foreach r2 generate COUNT(r1) as c, r1;
r4 = filter r3 by c > 1;
r5 = foreach r4 generate FLATTEN(r1);
dump r5;
```

However, the order is not reserved.

Comment: You could use the rank function, and then at the end just order by rank in order to preserve the order of the set